# unable to find where memory leaked

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, destructor, delete-operator

Hi I am currently working on my first object orientated c++ project, and when I use valgrind to check memory leakage it outputs:

```
32 (24 direct, 8 indirect) bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 2 of 2
==1761165==    at 0x4839E86: operator new(unsigned long) (vg_replace_malloc.c:344)
==1761165==    by 0x403E5C: Game::Game() (game.cpp:3)
==1761165==    by 0x404711: Game::loadGame(std::istream&) (game.cpp:109)
==1761165==    by 0x4024B2: main (main.cpp:29)
```

So now I go to game.cpp:3 to check what happened(in game.cpp:109, I called  Game* temp_game=new Game), and in line 3 I called the constructor

```
Game::Game() : game_entity(new EntityVec) {
}
```

So I guess at some point, I didn't free EntityVec. But after double checking my code, especially loadGame function and my destructor:

```
Game *Game::loadGame(std::istream &in){
  Game* temp_game=new Game;
  temp_game->game_maze=Maze::read(in);
  if (temp_game->game_maze == nullptr) {
      delete temp_game;
      return nullptr;
  }
  char c;int x;int y;
  EntityControllerFactory* ecfac=EntityControllerFactory::getInstance();
  while (in>>c){
    Entity* temp_entity=new Entity;
    temp_entity->setGlyph(std::string(1,c));
    temp_game->addEntity(temp_entity);
    if (in >> c) {
        EntityController* temp_controller = ecfac->createFromChar(c);
        temp_entity->setController(temp_controller);
    }
    else {
        delete temp_game;
        return nullptr;
    }
    if (in >> c) {
        temp_entity->setProperties(std::string(1,c));
    }
    else {
        delete temp_game;
        return nullptr;
    }
    if((in>>x)&&(in>>y)){
        temp_entity->setPosition(Position(x,y));
      }
 else {
        delete temp_game;
        return nullptr;
    }
  }
  return temp_game;
}

Game::~Game(){

  delete game_ui;
  delete game_gameRules;
  delete game_maze;
  //delete[] game_entity;
  for(Entity* p: *game_entity){delete p;}
  //game_entity->clear();

}
```

I cannot find a spot where I forgot to free the game if loadgame fails.(If loadgame success and returned temp_game, then main should handled it by deleting it at the end). Can anyone give me some suggestions? Thank you so much.

Comment: Instead of patching the memory leak bug, you could do yourself a favor and migrate to using smart pointers like `std::unique_ptr`. Your memory leak bugs would basically disappear and you wouldn't have to worry about future ones.

Comment: Beware that your current approach will completely explode if you start paying attention to which function can throw and where. For example, what happens if `in >> c` or `setProperties` throw an exception? You should read about [RAII](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/raii), one of the fundamental techniques of modern C++ programming.

Comment: Do you delete it when `loadGame()` succeeds? You return a `new`'ed object, so your caller must be sure to clean it up. [Best practice](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#p8-dont-leak-any-resources) is to use `std::unique_ptr` or similar to let RAII handle all resource de/allocations. Then you don't need any explicit `delete`s and your memory leaks will virtually vanish because it is always clear *who* is cleaning up and *when* and because you cannot forget to do so.

Comment: After asking my professor, I think I am not allowed to use smart pointers in this project although it would be really convenient to use it. Also, our guideline tells us the given tests will all be valid so I don't have to worry about exception

Comment: @AdrianMole Thank you! I thought I have to do something like game_entity.erase(); now my code dont have leakages, thank you!

Comment: @M.Chen Then you can still use RAII by putting each kind of raw pointer into it's own class that has correct constructors and destructors. Then you just have to use instances of those "handle" classes instead of raw pointers everywhere. RAII doesn't depend on smart pointers, it was always possible to use it even before effective smart pointers were standard. Its just much easier with them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every `new` should have a corresponding `delete`. In your `Game` constructor, you use `new` to create `game_entity` - but the destructor doesn't delete it (only its 'members').

You need a `delete game_entity;` ***after*** the `for` loop in the destructor.